# Recargar automaticamente archivos en NodeJS

Tags: nodejs, npm, gulp, express

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto con `NodeJS`, y acabo de darme cuenta que debo reiniciar el server cada vez que hago mis cambios, ¿hay alguna manera de evitar esto?

Estoy trabajando con **`NodeJS 6.10`**, **`express 4.13`**, **`gulp 3.9`**, **`npm 3.10`**.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con "volver a correr el server para ver los cambios"?

Comment: NodeJs con express empaqueta un javascript y los publica; al realizar un cambio en un Javascript  para que se visualice se tiene que reiniciar el servicio

Comment: puedes usar node-dev o  nodemon

Comment: @JackNavaRow usé node-dev, justo lo que quería, gracias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

una buena alternativa de usar un `supervisor` es **[`nodemon`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24750395/reload-express-js-routes-changes-without-restarting-server)**:

> Monitorea tu aplicacion node.js  y reinicia automaticamente el servidor- Ideal para desarrollar

Para usar `nodemon`:

```
$ npm install nodemon -g
$ nodemon app.js
```

otra opcion es usar **`node-dev`**

```
npm install node-dev
```

esta herramienta incluso da una notificación cuando el servidor se vuelve a cargar y dará un mensaje de éxito o error.

para iniciar **`node-dev`** debes ejecutar la siguiente linea:

```
node-dev app.js
```

respuesta de la comunidad de [stackoverflow en ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24750395/reload-express-js-routes-changes-without-restarting-server)