# Monitorear App en Angular 6 y Nodejs API

Tags: nodejs, angular, express

He diseñado una Web con Angular 6 y un back-end con Express y NodeJS.

Tengo la idea de hacer un dashboard para controlar el número de visitas, cuantas consultas a la API realizan, eventos click en el front ...

Estoy perdido y no tengo claro por dónde empezar.

He visto que algunos hosting y herramientas lo hacen, pero en mi caso es un servidor privado y no tengo la opción del hosting.

Tengo que manejar eventos en angular y que estos se guarden en base de datos?

Necesitaria algun tipo de consejo, toda ayuda es buena.

Un saludo y gracias.

Comment: Te comento que esta pregunta se basa en opiniones, y creo que va a ser cerrada, preguntas como estas son debatibles en el [chat] y tu posees puntuacion suficiente como para acceder, adelante eres bienvenido

Comment: Muchas gracias por la información, tienes razon.

Comment: existe [nodemon](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/83660/28035), y si quieres supervisar existe algo en los repositorios de npm llamado [supervisor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/supervisor) lo he usado es interesante

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es una pregunta más bien de opinión personal, pero te puedo decir dos maneras que tienes de monitorear la web y tu API sencillamente.

### Si no quieres depender de servicios de terceros.

La mejor solución sería registrar los eventos que se realizan en una base de datos, la cual puedes retornar fácilmente en un dashboard propio.

---

### [Google Analytics](https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/)

Este servicio nos sería bastante útil a la hora de saber datos en tiempo real, retención de los usuarios, de donde son tus usuarios etc.

Ahora GA dispone de una API, con la cual podemos crear un Dashboard con los datos que nos brinda GA sobre nuestro sitio web, aunque solamente la recomiento para usarse en web y no con la API, ya que en la api realizas llamadas de todo tipo, GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE.

---

### Resumiendo

Una buena practica sería usar **Google Analytics** para los datos de la web, y registrar los eventos cuando los usuario hagan llamadas a la API, por ejemplo, cuando recibes la llamada al servidor, puedes crear un Middleware que se encargue de registrar ese evento que ha recibido la **API**, con valores como, los headers, el body, la query, todo esto del método ***req*** que recibiría.

**Middleware que recoja los datos de la llamada**

```
app.use('*', (req,res,next) => {
    console.log(req.method);

    guardarEnBD(req.method, req.headers, req.body)
    .then((data)=> {
        next()
    })
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias esto es a lo que me refería. :D

Comment: Me alegro de haberte podido ayudar!!

Comment: Hola @JuanLuisCaro, como recomendación, trata de no poner el código en una imagen. Es mas facil para la persona q lee tu respuesta.

Comment: @ManucoBianco tienes razón perdón por el despiste.